# Symfony setup directory on cloudways

Tags: symfony, cloudways

I want to set up symfony3 on cloudways. Path for application folder is `/home/master/applications/[appName]`. `pwd` in this dir: `conf  logs  private_html  public_html  ssl  tmp`.

As [this link](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/install-symfony-3-on-cloud/) says I should install symfony application in `public_html`. However, I know that `public_html` is the same as `web`. So an application should not live in that folder. So, I think to install folder directly in `/home/master/applications/[appName]` and change 'web' directory to `public_html`. Is that right? Do not other existing folders (conf, logs) interfere symfony app?

**Update**: I am going to setup a git repo for symfony app on server. So if symfony should be installed in `public_html/../` then all other files also will be tracked by git. I do not think that ssl should be tracked. Sure, I can add it to gitignore, but anyway.

Comment: The link you provide, of the cloudways page, provider INCORRECT info! they do not modify their webserver to point to the web directory, which allows access to files which should not be accessible (the files ABOVE the web dir), so basically that is an incorrect setup, which is pretty ^$#&% on their part ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am from cloudways. Let me tell you the whole process, Cloudways is a managed hosting so there are some restrictions. You can't install symfony in: `/home/master/applications/[appName]`. You need to move in **Public_html** which is not a typical public directory. Install Symfony in this folder and don't worry your other files are not exposed beside the web folder. Every file is securely hidden and the whole process is also tested by Symfony officials.

After installing symfony in public_html folder, you can point out the URL to web directory: [image]

Again nobody will have access to your files they are protected.

You can add `.gitignore` file to avoid unusual files to be tracked. I created some tutorials you can take guidance from them. here is the URL: https://www.cloudways.com/blog/php/symfony/.

Answer (score 0):

The `web` directory is the directory Symfony is served out of via the frontend controller `app.php` (or `app_{env}.php` for non-prod). This is separate in philosophy from where your web server serves from (apache, nginx, etc). The directory structure ultimately doesn't matter much in either case so long as you point your web server to the correct directory where your frontend controller lives.

This is a good starting point: http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html